# problems with deamontools-run and SV after upgrade to 16.04

Tags: upgrade, 16.04, kubuntu

i just upgraded to Kubuntu 16.04 from 14.04. However, installer warns me, it can be in unusable state. I haven't restarted yet and am afraid to do so.

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
Setting up daemontools-run (1:0.76-6ubuntu1) ...
start: Job is already running: svscan
dpkg: error processing package daemontools-run (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
daemontools-run
```

in postinstall file I see:

```
if test -z "$2"; then
  # not upgrading
  if grep '^SV:' /etc/inittab >/dev/null; then
    cat <<-\EOT >&2

There already is an SV entry in /etc/inittab.  In order to have this
package add an entry with the name SV to have daemontools' service
supervision started through sysvinit, you need to remove or rename
the current SV entry first.

Installation failed.

EOT
exit 1
  fi
```

and in inittab:

```
#-- daemontools-run begin
SV:123456:respawn:/usr/bin/svscanboot
#-- daemontools-run end
```

What is the problem and how to solve it?

Comment: Is kubuntu using sysvinit at all?